# Express framework - Is a route's execution always completed before execution can begin on a new route regardless of async?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I have a basic, mechanical question on the Node.js [Express](https://expressjs.com/) framework.

When a client hits an endpoint a route is executed.  For example,

```
app.get('/' function(req, res, next) {
    res.send('hello world');
}
```

If a second client hits an endpoint during the execution of this route does Express instruct the second route to wait until the first route is completely finished?

What if the route contains asynchronous code.  For example,

```
app.get('/' function(req, res, next) {

    // async function below
    bcrypt.compare(password, hash)
        .then()
        .catch();
}
```

Since `bcrypt.compare()` is asynchronous will Express begin executing the second client's route before the first client's route is completely finished?  Or alternately does Express run one route at a time regardless of async?

Comment: No, each client gets their own call to `function(req, res, next) {`

Comment: `will Express begin executing the second client's route before the first client's route is completely finished?` If there are any asynchronous I/O occurring for each request, then yes, it will.